# Importing another class in a python class and accessing Super Class attributes

Tags: python

I have a main class as follows:

```
from .model_plots import ModelPlots

class Classification(ModelPlots):
    """ Class to carry out machine learning tasks """        
    def __init__(self,train_X,train_Y,test_X,test_Y,param_grid,estimator, model_name):
        """ Constructor to initialze the data
        
        """            
        self.train_X=train_X
        self.train_Y=train_Y
        self.test_X=test_X
        self.test_Y=test_Y
        # The hyper parameter grid for this estimator
        self.param_grid=param_grid
        # The actual ML estimator from sklearn
        self.estimator=estimator
        # Text name of the ML estimator 
        self.model_name = model_name
```

The module `model_plots` is in the same directory as the above class module. So I am importing it via relative import as above.

My `model_plots.py` module looks as below:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
    
class ModelPlots(object): 
    """ Class containing methods to plot 
    Roc Curve and other plots

    """     
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def plot_ROC(self):
        """ This functions plots the ROC curve of the classifier"""    
        if self.model_name =='svm':
            false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, _ =roc_curve(self.test_Y, self.g_cv.best_estimator_.decision_function(self.test_X))
            roc_auc= auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
            plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
            plt.plot(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, 'r',label='AUC_'+ self.model_name + '= %0.2f'% roc_auc)
            plt.legend(loc='lower right')
            plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
            plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')  
                    
        else: 
            false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, _ =roc_curve(self.test_Y, self.g_cv.best_estimator_.predict_proba(self.test_X).T[1])
            roc_auc= auc(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate)
            plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
            plt.plot(false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate, 'b',label='AUC_'+ self.model_name + '= %0.2f'% roc_auc,c='red')
            plt.legend(loc='lower right')
            plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
            plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
```

So I am importing this `model_plots.ModelPlot` class into main `Classification` class module.

However in my editor it throws a bunch of problems:

```
Instance of 'ModelPlots' has no 'model_name' member
Instance of 'ModelPlots' has no 'test_Y' member
```

And so on. Basically all the variables which are used in `ModelPlots` are from initialized in the main module `Classification`'s `__init__` function.

Is this cadence wrong and `ModelPlot` won't be able to access `Classification` Class attributes?

Do I need to pass `Classification` attributes back to `ModelPlot` Class?

Comment: Please post the ***full*** error traceback so we can see **where** the error comes from. I have a feeling the error is not coming from the code you posted

Comment: This is just a problem with your editor. I’m cool with the idea of a base class having methods which access attributes which a child class has to create. Python is a dynamic language after all.

Comment: the error is the above I mentioned. Its the problems I see in VSCode Problem section

Comment: Do you mean it's an IDE inspection warning? Not a real runtime error? In that case it is just because VSC detects that you use `model_name` inside `plot_ROC` which is under `ModelPlots` class but `ModelPlots` objects don't have that attribute (it is not defined in `__init__`)... You rely on the fact that it is being called from a sub-class. As long as you don't get a real error it's fine, but you might consider changing the design

Comment: what would be the right design then?

Comment: It's hard to say with just a glimpse of your program. To me personally it seems weird to have a class use attributes that it doesn't define. I know that people do it and it's not considered a problem. To me, it feels weird and in those cases I tend to at least define the attributes with some default value and have the sub-classes override it

Comment: is there a way we can define it better like using some super.__ something?